# Play Html5 video and pause at specific points in time

Tags: javascript, youtube, html5-video

I have an array of points in time (seconds) like this :

```
var points = [1,5,7,9,23,37];
```

I want the video to play from 1 to 5 and then pause. Then some event happens (like button click) and it plays from 5 to 7 and then pauses and so on. How can I do this using js/jquery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just queue up the times (currentStopTime) and check the `currentTime` of the video. If currentTime >= currentStopTime then pause video, set currentStopTime to next time in the array.

```
var points = [1,5,7,9,23,37],
    index = 1,
    currentStopTime = points[index];

// start video using: video.currentTime = points[0], then video.play()

// run this from a timeupdate event or per frame using requestAnimationFrame
function checkTime() {
    if (video.currentTime >= currentStopTime) {
        video.pause();
        if (points.length > ++index) {       // increase index and get next time
            currentStopTime = points[index]
        }
        else {                               // or loop/next...
            // done
        }
    }
}
```

Then when paused, enable an action to happen, simply call play() to start video again. If you need an accurate restart time then force that time by adding:

```
...
    if (video.currentTime >= currentStopTime) {
        video.pause();
        video.currentTime = currentStopTime;
        index++;
        ....
```